# Como crear una tabla en htm con diferentes cantidades de filas pero que todas encajen

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando replicar el comportamiento de esta tabla, pero de la manera en la que lo estoy haciendo la tabla se deforma, pues las rows se desequiparan como pueden ver en la foto, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comportamiento que quiero imitar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como de ve mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí mi código de HTML:

```
 <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Existing System</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 100%" >
                <td style="width: 50%;">Number of Pumps</td>
                <td># of Pumps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Design Water Flow Capacity (Name Plate)/td>
                <td>Nameplate Flow</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estimated Building Flow Demand*</td>
                <td>max flow</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Design Pressure Boost (Name Plate)</td>
                <td>Pump Head</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gauge Pressure (based on walkthrough, See Appendix C)</td>
                <td>Measured Head</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Energy Saving Summary</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>EXISTING</td>
                <td>PROPOSED</td>
                <td>SAVINGS</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Energy Consumption (kWh)</td>
                <td>Existing System cons</td>
                <td>Grundfos Pump cons</td>
                <td>Energy savings kwh</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr> 

        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este otro a ver si te funciona mejor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid black 1px;
            column-span: none;
        }

        tr{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid black 1px;
        }

        td{            
            text-align: center;
            border: solid black 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Existing System</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width: 100%" >
            <td style="width: 50%;">Number of Pumps</td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"># of Pumps</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Design Water Flow Capacity (Name Plate)/td>
            <td>Nameplate Flow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Estimated Building Flow Demand*</td>
            <td>max flow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Design Pressure Boost (Name Plate)</td>
            <td>Pump Head</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gauge Pressure (based on walkthrough, See Appendix C)</td>
            <td>Measured Head</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Energy Saving Summary</th>
        </tr>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">EXISTING</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">PROPOSED</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">SAVINGS</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%;">Energy Consumption (kWh)</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">Existing System cons</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">Grundfos Pump cons</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;">Energy savings kwh</td>
            <td style="width: 17.5%;"></td>
        </tr> 
    </table> 

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Un millón de gracias por tu tiempo bro, con este si me funciona 

Comment: @Tony  de nada, cualquier cosa me comentas!